# JAVA: replaceAll reg pattern

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Considering the following string:

```
String s = "/static/201105-3805-somerandom/images/optional-folder/filename.gif";
```

How can I remove the "static/201105-3805-somerandom/" part?
The "201105-3805-somerandom" part is completely random but always is composed of:
- 6 digits
- the "-" char
- {1, n} digit chars
- the "-" char
- {1, n} digit and letter chars

If I use `"/static/[0-9]*-[0-9]*-*/";`, it replaces everything to the last / instead of the one just after the "{1, n} digit and letter chars", what am I missing?

Comment: if it is always 3 slashes, you don't need a regex. just use the `indexOf`-method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceAll("^/static/\\d{6}-\\d{1,}-.*?/","")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing it to this:

```
/static/[0-9]*-[0-9]*-.*?/
```

`*` is by default greedy, specifying `*?` makes it reluctant.

Alternativaly, you could also do this without a regular expression like this:

```
String s = "/static/201105-3805-somerandom/images/optional-folder/filename.gif";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf('/', "/static/".length())));
```

This will start searching for `/` starting at the index immediately after the static part.  It will output:

```
/images/optional-folder/filename.gif
```

Answer (score 2):

You need non-greedy *:

```
"/static/[0-9]*-[0-9]*-.*?/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String s = "/static/201105-3805-somerandom/images/optional-folder/filename.gif";
    String regex = "/static/\\d{6}-\\d{4}-.*?/";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(regex, "")); // "images/optional-folder/filename.gif"
```

You where using a "greedy" match `.*`, but you needed a non-greedy match `.*?`

Answer (score 0):

Try `"/static/[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9a-zA-A]*?/"` maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
/static/[0-9]{6}-[0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*//
```

Your last * before the / simply matched all following characters (including the forward slash), so you need to be more specific and us [a-zA-Z0-9] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Other than regex, it will work if "/images..." are fixed:

```
String given = "/static/201105-3805-somerandom/images/optional-folder/filename.gif";
String replaced = given.substring(given.indexOf("/images"), given.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on @John's answer, if the `String` format should not deviate from the OPs requirement, where "somerandom" is restrained to digit and letter characters, then the following regular expression would work:

```
"/static/\\d{6}-\\d+-\\p{Alnum}+/"
```

This assumes the characters are US-ASCII.  If, however, you need to support Unicode characters (see [Unicode General Category](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch04.pdf), section 4.5, page 126), you could use the following regular expression:

```
"/static/\\d{6}-\\d+-(\\p{Lu}|\\p{Ll}|\\p{Nd})+/"
```

And if "somerandom" changes to be truly random (excluding the `/` character), the following would work:

```
"/static/\\d{6}-\\d+-[^/]+/"
```